# TopComponent (module) loading sequence in a project

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am new in Java and NetBeans. I have a Java project which has few modules and each module uses TopComponent.

The dependency between the modules are set in module properties. For example say the project has four modules: A, B, C, and D. Where, A is dependent on B and C. C is dependent on D. Having defined this dependency I assumed that the modules (TopComponent) will load on the hierarchy, i.e., D, C, B, and A. But this is not happening.

I searched through web and read some articles, but failed to figure out how to set the module loading sequence in NetBeans project?

Comment: What is a module? Java has only classes and jar-packages.

Comment: In netbeans a project can be organized into several modules https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projecttype.html#creatingthemoduleproject

Answer (score 1):

Pascal, you are new to Java and NetBeans and you are starting with NetBeans RCP? That's hardcore. Slow down! Start with plain Swing JDialog/JFrame stuff instead